# SQL EXEC query with wildcard parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I'm using SQL Server 2012 to query an IBM iSeries using the below T-SQL SP:

```
   exec ('select 
    TRIM (vhitno) AS Item,
    TRIM (mmitds) AS Description,
    TRIM (SUBSTRING (vhitno,12,4)) AS Size,
    vhalqt AS Available 
    from m3fdbtest.oagrln
    left outer join 
    m3fdbtest.mdeohe on vhcono=uwcono and vhcuno=uwcuno and vhagno=uwagno and vhitno=uwobv1
    left outer join 
    m3fdbtest.mitmas ON vhcono = mmcono AND vhitno = mmitno
    where 
    uwcono=1
    and 
    uwcuno=''JBHE0001''
    and
    uwagst=''20''
    and
    vhitno LIKE ? '
    , '%' + @Search + '%') at M3_TEST_ODBC
```

The paramater being passed, @Search needs to be a wild card.  I keep receiving the message:

```
Incorrect syntax near '%'.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using SQL server '&' is not valid, use +, but that whole last line looks a bit funky to me. In these scenarios, you can use PRINT, to get the SQL out and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: And that closing ' on the second-to-last line seems out of order as well.

Comment: I changed the '&' to a '+' and removed the closing ',' but still a no go....

Comment: @Michael you also do not have an AND or OR between the second to last, and the last line. 'at' is not valid either. Did you fix closing ' as suggested? Update the question with your new code if needs be.

Comment: updated to latest code

Comment: I think double vertical bars are the DB2 string concatenation operator in DB2 for iSeries.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work - thank you @Dan Guzman you are correct about the vertical bars:

```
@Search nvarchar(50) = ' '

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

   exec ('select 
    TRIM (vhitno) AS Item,
    TRIM (mmitds) AS Description,
    TRIM (SUBSTRING (vhitno,12,4)) AS Size,
    vhalqt AS Available 
    from m3fdbtest.oagrln
    left outer join 
    m3fdbtest.mdeohe on vhcono=uwcono and vhcuno=uwcuno and vhagno=uwagno and vhitno=uwobv1
    left outer join 
    m3fdbtest.mitmas ON vhcono = mmcono AND vhitno = mmitno
    where 
    uwcono=1
    and 
    uwcuno=''JBHE0001''
    and
    uwagst=''20''
    and
    vhitno LIKE ''%'' || ? || ''%'' '
    ,  @Search ) at M3_TEST_ODBC
```

Comment: The double vertical bars are sometimes the concat operator.  Depends on the language.  Best practice is to use the `CONCAT` operator

Answer (score 0):

on IBM iseries when you want to select with wilcard, you must use 'LIKE' instead of '='.

(vhitno like ?  or  mmitds like ?')

ex: vhitno like '%test%'